# Dynamic AJAX DD from Javascript nested array

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Basically I have the most popular code in the world for a dynamic dependant dropdown using PHP & MySQL, but I'm trying to populate the select option text and option value from an array, let's say the id as the option value, and the name as the option text; I found a thread that exactly depicts what I am trying to do, but it is not working for me (the dyanmic dropdown works like a charm).
Here's the link:
http://forums.phpfreaks.com/index.php?topic=287884.0

And here's my code;

```
`for (i=0;i<myarray.length;i++)
 {
 var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
 optn.text = myarray[i][0];
 optn.value = myarray[i][1];
 document.testform.id_proveedor.options.add(optn);
 }`
```

And the part of the code from the dd.php

```
`while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
$str=$str.'new Array("'.$nt[id_proveedor].'","'.$nt[nombre].'"),';
}
$str=substr($str,0,(strLen($str)-1)); // Removing the last char , from the string
echo "new Array($str)";`
```

Any ideas on why the code is not working?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that this script uses "evaluate" function of javascript and I don't think it is a good think. 
IMO the best practice would be such a code in php, using JSON

```
$result = array();
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
   $result[]=$nt;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

And in your AJAX code you just have to use `var myarray=JSON.parse(response);`to have your array to traverse.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but, I can't get it working, i replaced the line

Comment: `var myarray=eval(httpxml.responseText);`

Comment: with the one you gave me, and I also replace the part of the code I posted here with the one you gave me, but so far no luck, could you point me to a tutorial to where I can get this? or if you can give me a bit more deep explanation? Thanks!